# Need help in PostgreSQl Query connected via Python

Tags: python, postgresql

Getting an error while filtering the PostgreSQL data.

```py
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = "Database", user = "DB_User", password = "DB_Pwd!", host = ""DB_Host, port = "4321") 

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Source_Format not in (%s)", ('Weeks',))
```

> InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

I'm trying to filter the table data by not including the Weeks records from the Source_Format column but getting the above error.

Comment: 1) I see nothing obviously wrong with your SQL (but the `connect` line is not syntactically correct Python!). 2) That error message means that something has gone wrong earlier in the transaction, but in the code you show there is nothing else that can go wrong. This makes me suspect that the problem is in some code that you are not showing us.

Comment: 1) host = ""DB_Host should be host = "DB_Host". 2) This port = "4321" does not look like the correct one for Postgres